# Query Filter with And and Or logic in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, filter, logical-operators

I have to build a query that should have both And/Or logic. In the below logic, if the user last name and date of purchase fields from UI are mandatory, where as the customer name and customer Id, either of those one should be entered. However, in the queryFilter in the below code, I need to build filter such that, if user enters both customer name and customer Id, atleast one of those two values is correct, I need to retrieve the data. That means, I need to build an OR operator for customer name and customer Id. Because, even one of those two values matches in database records, it should be returned. But, Currently with the below code, I was not able to retrieve the data:

```
List<QueryFilter> filter = new List<QueryFilter>();

            filter.Add(new Core.QueryFilter("ProductName", Core.QueryOperator.Equal, productName));
            filter.Add(new Core.QueryFilter("DateOfPurchase", Core.QueryOperator.Equal, dop));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName))
            {
                filters.Add(new Core.QueryFilter("CustName", Core.QueryOperator.Equal, customerName, QueryLogic.Or));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerId))
            {
                filters.Add(new Core.QueryFilter("CustomerID", Core.QueryOperator.Equal, customerId, QueryLogic.Or));
            }
```

Below if the QueryFilter class:

```
public class QueryFilter
    {
        public string Field { get; set; }
        public QueryOperator Operator { get; set; }
        public QueryLogic Logic { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<QueryFilter> Filter { get; set; }

        public QueryFilter() { }

        public QueryFilter(string field, QueryOperator op, string value, QueryLogic logic = 0)
        {
            Field = field;
            Operator = op;
            Value = value;
            Logic = logic;
        }

    }
```

Can someone help me out where I am doing wrong?

Comment: How would you know one of the two values is correct? Can you post the code that determines this?

Comment: Actually I was trying to fetch data from database based on the above filter. Simply passing this query in my linq. There is no logic built as of now to check the values entered were correct. That is what I was trying to build based on this query filter. Suppose user enters 1st two fields correct and CustomerName correct, but not correct customerId, still I have to retrieve the record from database. This is what I was trying to build.

Comment: How do you build *Where* condition for *SQL* query using *QueryFilter*? Could you post the code or at least a condition you get when *CustName* and *CustomerID* are specified?